# C random numbers that logic bit sum(OR) is equal to max unsigned short value

Tags: c, random, bit

Task is to write a program that counts an avarage number of unsigned short ints needed to make their bit logical sum(a1 OR a2 OR a3…) be equal to 111..1. I'd really be thankful for any kind of help. Edit: adapted like that and loop still doesnt exit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){

int count=0;
unsigned short sum = 0;
unsigned short USHRT_MAX = 65535;

while(sum != USHRT_MAX ){
    unsigned short r = (unsigned short)rand()%USHRT_MAX;
    sum = sum | r;
    count++;
}
printf("the answer is : %d numbers\n", count);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Use an unsigned integer if you are playing with bits.

Comment: @Rafal `sum=255` - not a comparison.

Comment: You need to generate a new random number in the while loop. And you need an outer loop to compute the average.

Comment: Why 255?  `USHRT_MAX` is at least 65535?

Comment: Pedantically speaking, this is not solvable on all  platforms as the range of `unsigned short` may have more positive values than `int` - the return type of `rand()`.  Yet only odd/old/and current 16-bit processors machines would have that.

Comment: Note: experimentally found the average to be about `ln2(int_bit_width-1/3) + 1.3`  YMMV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sum=255`is an assignment a not compare operator. Apart from this you want to continue as long as `sum` is not equal `USHRT_MAX`. If you write a `return` instruction into a loop without any condition, the loop will terminate directly.
To get different numbers you have to call `rand` inside your loop. Function `rand` returns a value of type `int`. Adapt your code like this:

```
int main(){

    int count=0;
    unsigned short sum = 0;
    while(sum != USHRT_MAX){
        unsigned short r = (unsigned short)rand();
        sum = sum | r;
        count++;
    }
    printf("the answer is : %d numbers\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```